# Azure Powershell cmdlets fails

Tags: powershell, azure, installation, powershell-cmdlet

I have requirement to configure secondary interface on azure vm.For this we require Add-AzureNetworkInterfaceConfig cmdlets which is not recognized when i am executing the command.Could someone help me to install cmdlets on azure powershell.

Comment: I think it would be better to ask your question at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the latest cmdlets (can be installed from here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/). Current version is 0.8.14. You can check your version by running `get-module azure`.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the release you require from here [AzurePowershell Release](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases)